# how to use awk command to cut field?

Tags: shell

there is a file ,which you can get by command `ps aux` in linux.

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.0   2280   732 ?        Ss   08:20   0:00 init [2]  
root       327  0.0  0.1   2916  1456 ?        Ss   08:20   0:00 udevd --daemon
root      1681  0.0  0.0   2376   800 ?        Ss   08:20   0:00 /sbin/rpcbind -w
root      2071  0.0  0.1  27920  1708 ?        Sl   08:20   0:00 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -c5
```

i want to get the content of last field,such as:

```
COMMAND
init [2]
udevd --daemon
/sbin/rpcbind -w
/usr/sbin/rsyslogd -c5
```

when i use , $ awk '{print $11}'  test,i get:

```
COMMAND
init
udevd
/sbin/rpcbind
/usr/sbin/rsyslogd
```

when i use ，$ awk '{print $12}' test，i get :

```
[2]
--daemon
-w
-c5
```

how can i do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<11;i++)$i="";print }'
```

or you can just do:

```
awk '{print $11,$12}'
```

Comment: First solution in this post is best, as you never know what type of command is going to show up and how many spaces are going to be in it.

Answer (score 2):

You can loop over the words of the last field and print them:

```
ps aux | awk '{ for( i=11 ; i <=NF ; i++ ) { printf( "%s ", $i ) } ; print "" }'
```

If you want to process the command afterwards, you can put it in a variable:

```
ps aux | awk '{ CMD = "" ; for( i=11 ; i <=NF ; i++ ) { CMD = CMD " " $i } ; sub( /^ /, "", CMD ) ; print CMD }'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're not required to use awk, the following also works:

```
ps aux | tr -s ' ' ' ' | cut -d' ' -f11-
```

Deciphering that a bit.  Since `ps` separates its columns with spaces,

```
tr -s ' ' ' '
```

replaces repeated strings of spaces (as specified by the first string [the first set of ' ']) with a single space (specified in the second string).  Now, since the fields are now single space separated, we can use

```
cut -d' ' -f11-
```

which says that fields are separated by a space (the character after the '-d'), and to select fields 11 to the end of the line (denoted as the '-f11-').

This might seem a little more complicated at first look, but it really simplifies parsing separated-value strings once you get the hang of it.

Answer (score 1):

For the above output, this should work:

```
ps aux | cut -c66-
```

NOTE: Watch out the last '-'. If you miss it, you will get only the 66th char!!!

However for this to work every time, the **COMMAND** column should start at 66th char position. If it is different, note the **COMMAND** column's number and change the cut command like this

```
cut -c<column#>-
```

Answer (score 0):

The existing answer didn't work on awk version 20070501, it printed leading spaces. This worked.

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<11;i++)$i="";$0=$0;$1=$1;print}'
```